# Create Father Son Relationship table from 3 column data table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a table like that in SQL (Oracle 19c):

| ID | Name | FatherID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category1 | null |
| 2 | Category1.1 | 1 |
| 3 | Category1.1.1 | 2 |
| 4 | Category2 | null |
| 5 | Category2.1 | 4 |

My data source actually a collection in Oracle Apex (loaded from a xlsx file) that is structured like that:

| seq_id | C001 | C002 | C003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category1 | null | null |
| 2 | Category1 | Category1.1 | null |
| 3 | Category1 | Category1.1 | Category1.1.1 |
| 4 | Category2 | null | null |
| 5 | Category2 | Category2.1 | null |

I've tried to make a WITH statement with 5 support tables and then unioning all at the last step but something is flapping at each query execution and i get an inconsistent result at each execution. I've tried to order every result of the temps tables to get the data to stay ordered but it isn't working.

I'm not a SQL master and so I'm here to ask for some help. How can i approach this problem?

This is my code:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT  = ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'';

BEGIN
    insert /*+ append */ into conn_category
    
    WITH  
        default_data as (
        SELECT c001, c002, c003
        FROM APEX_collections
        WHERE collection_name = 'DL_CATEGORIE_PORTALE_COLLECTION'
   
        ),
        cat1_lvl as (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY c001 asc) as ID_PARENT, c001 as c001_new
        from default_data
        group by c001 ),
    
        cat2_lvl as (
            select distinct null as ID_PARENT,  a.c001 from
            default_data a
            , cat1_lvl b
            where
            a.c001 = b.c001_new
            UNION ALL
            select distinct  b.ID_PARENT,  a.c002 from
            default_data a
            , cat1_lvl b
            where
            a.c001 = b.c001_new),
    
        cat3_lvl as (
            select rownum as ID_PARENT, a.c001 from
            ( cat2_lvl ) a ),
        
        result as (
            select 
            ID_PARENT as ID_CATEGORY_PARENT,
            c001 as NAME
            from cat2_lvl
            UNION ALL
            select  
            b.ID_PARENT as ID_CATEGORY_PARENT,
            a.c003 as NAME
            from
            default_data a,
            cat3_lvl b
            where
            a.c002 = b.c001
            AND a.c003 is not null    
        ),
        export as (
        select 
        rownum as ID,
        name,
        id_category_parent,
        TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as created_at,
        TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as updated_at,
        NULL as processed_at
        from result )
        
        select * from export order by id;

END;
```

Comment: We cannot tell you what the problem is without seeing your SQL.

Comment: And what is the expected result ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie the expected result is the first table in the post.

Comment: This is the ugly query i made < Query added in the first post>

Comment: The part that get "flapping" (ie giving a different result each time i run the query) is the second select after UNION ALL in cat2_lvl table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT seq_id,
       COALESCE(C003, C002, C001) AS name,
       PRIOR seq_id AS father_id
FROM   table_name t
START WITH C002 IS NULL
AND        C003 IS NULL
CONNECT BY
   (LEVEL = 2 AND PRIOR C001 = C001 AND C002 IS NOT NULL AND C003 IS NULL)
OR (LEVEL = 3 AND PRIOR C001 = C001 AND PRIOR C002 = C002 AND C003 IS NOT NULL)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (seq_id, C001, C002, C003) AS
SELECT 1, 'Category1', null,          null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Category1', 'Category1.1', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Category1', 'Category1.1', 'Category1.1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Category2', null,          null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Category2', 'Category2.1', null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SEQ_ID | NAME | FATHER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category1 | *null* |
| 2 | Category1.1 | 1 |
| 3 | Category1.1.1 | 2 |
| 4 | Category2 | *null* |
| 5 | Category2.1 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dcxw9vJD)

Comment: Thank you @MT0! I didn't use connect by but now i will study this code and hierarchical queries in general (i've tried and it works with my data!)

Comment: I have a bug with my data and i trying to understand why it happens, but when i have C003 not null (so, with some data), C002 father of C003 qnd C003 itself doesn't show up

Comment: Ok i found it: i didn't have a row with C001+C002 but only C001+C002+C003